# Defining url / title for "add to home" function in mobile browser (not pwa)

Tags: android, html, vue-router

I'm trying to manipulate the contents which are used to create a browser shortcut to a smartphone home screen.

What I have:

- a web-app written in vue.js
- in-app navigation with vue router and url hashes
- a note for the user to use the "add to home screen" function of his browser
- an user using chrome on android

My problem is that the user always bookmarks the "current" url e.g. "page.html#/route" but I really want him to only bookmark "page.html".

(btw: I can't use a PWA because I need camera access and iOS doesn't allow camera access in PWAs)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: use a .webmanifest file and add a "start_url". Apparently that works for non PWAs, too.